# Need to use Expanded widget to avoid overflow, but am not getting the desired size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to develop a profile page with the following

`without expanded`

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 50, 25, 0),
            child: Column(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                        child: Text(
                          "Edit Profile",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.indigoAccent.shade400,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                            onTap: this.updatePhoto,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 55.0,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent.shade400,
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 50,
                                    child: ClipOval(
                                        child: (this._image != null)
                                            ? Image.file(this._image)
                                            : Image.asset(
                                                "assets/no_img.jpg"))))),
                        Positioned(
                            top: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                radius: 20,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: this.updatePhoto,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                  color: Colors.blue.shade800,
                                )))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                          onTap: this.updateName,
                          title: Text("Name",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500, fontSize: 13)),
                          subtitle: Text(this.name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next, size: 35))),
                ]),
                Divider(height: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                          onTap: this.updatePhoneNumber,
                          title: Text("Phone",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500, fontSize: 13)),
                          subtitle: Text(this.phoneNumber,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next, size: 35)))
                ]),
                Divider(height: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                          onTap: this.updateEmail,
                          title: Text("Email",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500, fontSize: 13)),
                          subtitle: Text(this.email,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next, size: 35))),
                ]),
                Divider(height: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                          onTap: this.updateAbout,
                          title: Text("Tell us about yourself",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500, fontSize: 13)),
                          subtitle: Text(this.about,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next, size: 35))),
                ]),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Currently my page looks exactly how I want
[image: Without Expanded Widget]

However, when I add text to my bottom ListTile, it returns an error `Renderflex overflowed by x pixels`. I found in the Flutter docs that it's recommended that I use the `Expanded` Widget in order to keep from overflowing. After adding that, my app looks like this:

`with expanded`

```dart
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 50, 25, 0),
            child: Column(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                        child: Text(
                          "Edit Profile",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.indigoAccent.shade400,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                            onTap: this.updatePhoto,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 55.0,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent.shade400,
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 50,
                                    child: ClipOval(
                                        child: (this._image != null)
                                            ? Image.file(this._image)
                                            : Image.asset(
                                                "assets/no_img.jpg"))))),
                        Positioned(
                            top: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                radius: 20,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: this.updatePhoto,
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                                  color: Colors.blue.shade800,
                                )))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                          onTap: this.updateName,
                          title: Text("Name",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500, fontSize: 13)),
                          subtitle: Text(this.name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next, size: 35))),
                ])),
                Divider(height: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                Expanded(
                    child: Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                          onTap: this.updatePhoneNumber,
                          title: Text("Phone",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500, fontSize: 13)),
                          subtitle: Text(this.phoneNumber,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next, size: 35)))
                ])),
                Divider(height: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                Expanded(
                    child: Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                          onTap: this.updateEmail,
                          title: Text("Email",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500, fontSize: 13)),
                          subtitle: Text(this.email,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next, size: 35))),
                ])),
                Divider(height: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                Expanded(
                    child: Row(children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListTile(
                          onTap: this.updateAbout,
                          title: Text("Tell us about yourself",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade500, fontSize: 13)),
                          subtitle: Text(this.about,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.navigate_next, size: 35))),
                ])),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

[image: With Expanded Widget]

I no longer get the overflow error, but I would like to still have my app look like the first photo. Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: You can add another Expanded to your Column and set `flex` factor to every Expanded to get desirable proportions, like set flex to 1 for your ListTiles, and then to last added Expanded set for example flex 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Flexible` instead of `Expanded`. And only use it on your `error` causing widget, i.e your last list tile, no need to use it on every row and every listTile. If you use Expanded on the last `"Tell us about yourself"` Listtile, it should also work, without spacing out `email` and `name`.